# Problem with Chunk Files durring ng serve after update to Angular 12

Tags: angular, chunking, angular12

Is anybody else facing this problem? After an update to Angular 12, all the files of my application are being chunked in development, at run ng serve.

Now I can't debug on the browser once all the files are compressed and the names of the files are numbers, not the real file name.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiCUQ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czc4p.png)

Comment: In your angular.json, inside dev build settings, there would be many options. Try researching and tweaking on that.

Comment: I will try that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 12 needs additional configuration so that not all files are compressed in development build. Add, in the angular.json file, inside architect -> build -> configurations:

```
"configurations": {
  "development": {
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "optimization": false,
    "vendorChunk": true,
    "extractLicenses": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "namedChunks": true
  },
  "production": {
    ...
  }
}
```

And under serve -> configurations:

```
"serve": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development"
    }
  }
}
```

Run the app with `ng serve myapp --configuration development`. Or change your default configuration for "ng serve" eg:

```
"serve": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    ...
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular v12, production builds are enabled by default. For your development server, you need to disable the production settings. Make sure your `angular.json` is set up like the following:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-project-name": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              ...
            },
            ...
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```